# Using SweetAlerts 2 themes

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

We're looking to use the themes, but we can't figure out how to do so - we're not very experienced developers.
We understand that we need to import the corresponding CSS file for the desired theme, but how do you then apply it?
My goal is to have a dropdown with the different themes and show the modal with the selected theme.

The easiest would be to have a "theme" parameter in the options as the other settings, but there are none. We'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: A quick search on your favorite search-engine shows you how to configure, implement and use it -> https://sweetalert2.github.io/#usage

Comment: Thanks for the sweet comment @iLuvLogix, however, it's precisely this part that we're not able to understand.
It seems like we have to import the corresponding CSS stylesheet file, but how can we manage to have a dropdown to select it, as importing multiple stylesheet will override each other?

Comment: Ever heard of `@mixin global-theme($theme) {....`  or `document.body.classList.remove` & `document.body.classList.add`?

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to use them properly but it made me discover the `$('head').append` which appears to be working.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by appending the CSS to the page header.

```
if (properties.theme === "Default") {$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@sweetalert2/theme-default@5.0.11/default.min.css">')}
```